# How to set up Windows 64 bit on Parallels?

Tags: windows, parallels

- Got Parallels installed
- Downloaded and set up Windows image from - https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/
- System type is 32-bit Operating System

How to change 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS on Parallels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those images are for 32-bit version. They don't provide 64-bit because you are really only supposed to run IE and test your site.

You can't change the bitness of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks Chet, much appreciated.